# iPhone - Getting zip file name and folder same as that of zip name

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsfilemanager

I'm using the following code to get list of zip files from a folder in my iphone application.

```
NSFileManager* fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray* files = [fileMan contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myFolder error:&err];
NSArray* exts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"zip", nil]; 
files = [files pathsMatchingExtensions:exts];
```

I'm using above code to remove zip files in "myFolder"
In "myFolder", along with my zip, i also have unzip folder with the same name. For example if zip file name is A.zip, unzip folder name is "A".
My question is how can I get "A.zip" and "A". I don't want to have code that extracts the file name and then getting the folder...... I want to know if any other alternative is there

Comment: I didn't understand your exact problem are you not able to remove files with above method or is there anything else you want to do? Please clarify more.

Comment: In one shot I want to delete zip and associated unzip folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following codes.

```
NSString *fileName = [[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];  
NSString *fileType = [path pathExtension];
```

where `path` is a `NSString`.